# Secondary Join Condition Ignored in Insert SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following models (to which I still need to add some appropriate validation):

```
class Participant(db.Model):
    player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'),
                          primary_key=True)
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'), primary_key=True)
    winner = db.Column(db.Boolean)


class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    avatar = db.Column(db.String(120))
    skill = db.Column(db.Integer)


def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)


class Game(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    loser_score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    loser = db.relationship('Player',
                              secondary=Participant.__table__,
                              secondaryjoin=and_(
                                 Player.id == Participant.player_id,
                                 Participant.winner == False))
    winner = db.relationship('Player',
                             secondary=Participant.__table__,
                             secondaryjoin=and_(
                                 Player.id == Participant.player_id,
                                 Participant.winner == True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Game %r>' % (self.id)
```

These work great when I'm retrieving data. When I insert a Game object though, it ignores the 'winner' field in the Participant table and generates these SQL statements:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
INSERT INTO game (date, loser_score) VALUES (?, ?)
('2015-02-13 19:31:04.804182', 15)
INSERT INTO participant (player_id, game_id) VALUES (?, ?)
(2, 2)
INSERT INTO participant (player_id, game_id) VALUES (?, ?)
(1, 2)
```

I would expect it to generate:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
INSERT INTO game (date, loser_score) VALUES (?, ?)
('2015-02-13 19:31:04.804182', 15)
INSERT INTO participant (player_id, game_id, winner) VALUES (?, ?, 0)
(2, 2)
INSERT INTO participant (player_id, game_id, winner) VALUES (?, ?, 1)
(1, 2)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: How are you inserting the data?

Comment: I'm using Flask-Restless and sending a post request to the generated end point.

Comment: (although, if I use session.add the same thing will happen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `sqlalchemy` to be able to handle cases like this out-of-the-box. The code below is what I would use in such case:

```
class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    avatar = db.Column(db.String(120))
    skill = db.Column(db.Integer)


class Participant(db.Model):
    player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'),
                          primary_key=True)
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'), primary_key=True)
    winner = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    # relationships
    player = db.relationship('Player')


class Game(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    loser_score = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # relationships
    game_players = db.relationship(
        'Participant',
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection("winner"),
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        backref="game",
    )

    # this allows usage like: my_game.player[True/False] = my_player
    players = association_proxy(
        'game_players', 'player',
        creator=lambda win, pla: Participant(winner=win, player=pla),
    )

    # winner: an alias to self.players[True]
    @property
    def winner(self):
        return self.players.get(True)

    @winner.setter
    def winner(self, value):
        self.players[True] = value

    @winner.deleter
    def winner(self):
        del self.players[True]

    # loser: an alias to self.players[False]
    @property
    def loser(self):
        return self.players.get(False)

    @loser.setter
    def loser(self, value):
        self.players[False] = value

    @loser.deleter
    def loser(self):
        del self.players[False]
```

which allows you to use the code like:

```
g1 = Game(...)
g1.players[True] = playerA
g1.players[False] = playerB
```

and with properties winner/loser even like:

```
g1 = Game(...)
g1.winner = playerA
g1.loser = playerB
```

Read [Proxying to Dictionary Based Collections](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#proxying-to-dictionary-based-collections) for more information on `attribute_mapped_collection` and its usage.